# Which Character Can Cause the Most  Knockback?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

My most common strategy in previous Soul Calibur games was to knock my opponent over the side of the stage.  I've missed a few editions of the game though (I think the last one I played was Soul Calibur 2), so I'm unfamiliar with most of the characters.

Which character or characters has the largest arsenal of attacks that inflict [substantial] knockback on an opponent?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's still asteroth and to a lesser extent nightmare.

Asteroth's shoulder ram `66K` is still a great way to get your opponent's near the edge.

Almost all of nightmare's `B` moves have a good amount of push back. His double punch `4B,B` moves both characters forward a good amount. A few of these when blocked will have your opponent next to the edge in the smallest arenas.

Note: be careful of just guard. Powerful moves meant to knock your enemies back are especially vulnerable to this new feature.

Comment: While I agree with you, I suggest elaborating further (perhaps mentioning specific moves) that would help out GnomeSlice more.